# Is it acceptable to simply plot an interaction instead of performing follow up tests?

Tags: regression, interaction

I have heard anecdotally that some people propose plotting interactions and interpreting the plots, rather than conducting follow up tests. Is this an acceptable approach? Is there a good reference to cite for this?

Edit: By acceptable I mean in terms of the most recent statistics guidelines for psychology.

Comment: Any question about "acceptability" needs to make it clear who it's supposed to be acceptable *to*. It's really no good asking if I'd accept it if (say) you are trying to publish in a psych journal or give a presentation on PhD work to a biology conference, since someone like me thinking "yeah, that's just the ticket" won't help you then (and many of us may not be able to guess what an audience we may not be familiar with could be induced to accept).

Answer (score 0):

When the interaction exists, follow-up test is still needed or necessary.

Suppose factor A has 3 levels and factor B has 3 levels. When interaction exists, it may be meaningless to test the difference between levels of factor A and that of factor B. But maybe the difference between A1 and B2 is interesting and can be tested. Also by follow-up test, the source of interaction could be detected.

If interaction is between factor A (3 levels) and a continue covariate, by follow-up test, you can find which  two lines are not parallel.

If only the plot is given, maybe no two means are exact the same, but some difference between means are statistically meaningful, and some of them are totally duo to the random error.